# Custom sms tone on HTC WM8S

Tags: 8.0, sms, ringtone

Hello I have HTC windows mobile 8S and I'd like to add new sms tone, as much as I googled I found ringtone2sms app, but I couldn't install it, is there any other way ( apps, updates, any other stuff ) to add new tones ? Or maybe someone know's good version of this ringtone2sms for my HTC WM8S ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ringtone via the method outlined on [windowsphone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/add-ringtones-to-my-phone), however, it seems like you can [only assign](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/why-can-i-not-change-the-text-message-tone-to-a/e06bac2f-2a4b-408f-90de-66891de65d22?msgId=34380235-3031-4d5a-aa63-c2dcb51a661d) your custom ringtone to calls.

Comment: I ask about sms tone, not ring tone.. 2 different tones...

Comment: Normally one would add a ringtone, then assign it to an alarm, sms, or other sound. In Windows Phone you can only assign a ringtone to an incoming call. Ringtone should not mean just one usage.